# Is there any SwiftData equivalent willSave?

Tags: swift, swift-data

With `NSManagedObject` there are a few hooks like `awakeFromInsert()` and `willSave()` among others.  Are there methods to override that can serve the same function?  `awakeFromInsert` can be replaced with the `init` method, but `willSave()` I currently use to update modification dates.  I'd like an easy way to do those, rather than observing all the properties that would update the modification date.

I've tried looking at expanded macros from the @Model but haven't seen anything that it looks like I can override, or hook into.

A couple ways that I could do this is observe all the properties that would cause the modification date to update, or create custom function for each property that updates the modification date as well.

These both seem inelegant, error prone and hard to maintain.  Anyone else have another solution?

Comment: There is a willSave notification for ModelContext if that could be helpful.

Comment: Did you get willSave to work? Doesn't work for me

Answer (score 4):

I've been unable to get the `ModelContext.willSave` notification to fire, but if I replace it with `Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextWillSave`. It will give fire and then if I peek inside of the ModelContext, `hasChanges`, and the various `.*ModelsArray` properties will have the changes in them.

In a view, add the following `.onReceive()` modifier, and define an `@Environment` for the SwiftData model context.

`@Environment(\.modelContext) private var context`

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for:Notification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextWillSave), perform: { notification in
            print(notification.name)
            print(self.context.hasChanges)
            print("Deletes: \(self.context.deletedModelsArray.count)")
            print("Updates: \(self.context.changedModelsArray.count)")
            print("Inserts: \(self.context.insertedModelsArray.count)")
        })
```

This makes me think that SwiftData could be described as a highly-opinionated layer sitting on top of CoreData.